# Como se ponen mas de una fuente en un mismo parrafo

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo un proyecto con HTML y CSS, y mi duda es si es posible que en un mismo párrafo haya dos tipos de fuentes diferentes (algunas letras deberían ser en una fuente y otras en otra), estuve buscando en internet, pero solo me salen respuestas con Wordpress

Comment: Si, si es posible

Comment: Podrías usar una etiqueta SPAN para dar formato al texto que deseas cambiar el estilo

Comment: Para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta sugiero leas [ask], edites y agregues que has intentado o investigado

Comment: Bueno, yo creia que algo habia intentado cuando decia esto: `estuve buscando en internet, pero solo me salen respuestas con Wordpress`... en fin, no todos saben googlear ni como hablar con google (eso tendria que ser de Primero de internet, pero desafortunadamente hay muchos que no saben expresarse ni buscar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encierra los textos en dos [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) distintos y en cada uno le pones una clase apuntando a un fuente distinto, previamente definidos con [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), por ejemplo:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Raleway'), local('Raleway-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v11/0dTEPzkLWceF7z0koJaX1A.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Bungee Inline'), local('BungeeInline-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/bungeeinline/v2/Tb-1914q4rFpjT-F66PLCTxObtw73-qQgbr7Be51v5c.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

.fuente1 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline';
}

.fuente2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et <span class="fuente1">dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam,</span> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span class="fuente2">Duis aute irure dolor 
in reprehenderit in voluptate </span>velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui 
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

**Explicación:**

*`<span>`*: Definición sacada de [esta página](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

> Es un contenedor en línea. **Sirve para aplicar estilo al texto** o
> agrupar elementos en línea.

Permite el uso de clases, por lo tanto encerramos el texto entre `<span class="fuente1">texto</span>` para delimitar el rango de actuación de esa clase.

*`@font-face`*: Definición sacada de [esta página](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

> permite al autor especificar fuentes online para visualizar en sus
> páginas web. Al permitir a los autores proporcionar sus propias
> fuentes, @font-face elimina la necesidad de depender del numero
> limitado de fuentes de usuarios instaladas en sus computadoras.

Y ahora solo nos quedaba definir las clases CSS usadas, *fuente1*  y *fuente2*, estableciendo el tipo de fuente mediante el uso de `font-family:`, apuntando a los *font-family* definidos en `@font-face`:

```css
    .fuente1 {
      font-family: 'Bungee Inline';
    }

    .fuente2 {
      font-family: 'Raleway';
      font-size: 25px;
    }
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Crea en css las clases que requieras, en tu archivo de HTML, utiliza la etiqueta que más te sea útil aplicando el estilo deseado.

```css
.class1 {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}

.class2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: orange;
}

.class3 {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label class="class1">Probando</label>
  <label class="class2">tipos de letras</label>
  <label class="class3">Distintos!</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Por favor leer [answer]

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: No quiero molestar a nadie, pero el elemento `<label>` no es para eso, es para acompañar campos de entrada más bien, con atributos propios como `for=`.   En cambio la de `<span>` es practicamente solo para eso.